# Intensity measure vs. Intensity function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, point-processes

Can someone please clarify the difference between an **"intensity measure"** and **"intensity function"** associated to point processes with an explanation including an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the intensity function is the density of the intensity measure. And not every measure has a density.

(But there might be other definitions out there)